# Processing $_POST elements for an AJAX call to update MYSQL table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a form that takes input from a MySQL tables for showing values and also updates it using certain action items.

Right now, I'm trying to work on an "UPDATE" functionality that would allow me to update the Comments and Status fields on the form to the newest changes. However, there is something wrong with my code. For one, it seems as if it's not calling the "ajax_updateBugStats.php" file.

The result is that it's not being updated in the MySQL tables.
Here is the form:

```
<form id = "bugStats">
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    ID
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    ISSUE
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    REFERER
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    URI
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    STATUS
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    COMMENTS
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    EMAIL
                                </th>
                                <!-- <th>
                                    USER
                                </th> -->
                                <th>
                                    TIME
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <select  id = "dropdown_action" name = "dropdown_action">
                                        <option id = "sub" type= "submit" name= "sub" value="UPDATE">UPDATE</input>
                                        <option id = "sub" type= "submit" name= "sub" value="EMAIL">EMAIL</input>
                                    </select>
                                    <input id = "sub" type= "submit" name= "sub" value="SUBMIT"/>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            </form>';

$sqlstring2 = "SELECT id, description, httpreferer, requesturi, status, comments, email, wpuserid, requesttime FROM isnew.bugtracker ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50";
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sqlstring2);
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
    $id = $row2['id'];
    $description = $row2['description'];
    $httpreferer = $row2['httpreferer'];
    $requesturi = $row2['requesturi'];
    $status = $row2['status'];
    $comments = $row2['comments']; 
    $email = $row2['email'];
    $requesttime = $row2['requesttime'];

                        echo '
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input form = "bugStats" id = "bugID" type = "hidden" name = "bugID['.$id.']" value = "'.$id.'">
                                    <strong>'.$id.'</strong>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    '.$description.'
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    '.$httpreferer.'
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    '.$requesturi.'
                                </td>
                                <!-- <td>
                                    '.$httpuseragent.'
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    '.$remoteaddress.'
                                </td> -->
                                <td>
                                    <select form = "bugStats" id = "status" name = "status['.$id.']">
                                        <option id = "blankStat" value= "" '.(($status == '')?'selected = "selected"':"").'>                                                        </option>;
                                        <option id = "openStat" value= "Opened" '.(($status == 'Opened')?'selected = "selected"':"").'>                     Opened                  </option>;
                                        <option id = "investigateStat" value= "Ticket - Investigated" '.(($status == 'Ticket - Investigated')?'selected = "selected"':"").'>    Ticket - Investigated   </option>;
                                        <option id = "inProgressStat" value= "Ticket - In Progress" '.(($status == 'Ticket - In Progress')?'selected = "selected"':"").'>   Ticket - In Progress    </option>;
                                        <option id = "closedStat" value= "Closed" '.(($status == 'Closed')?'selected = "selected"':"").'>                       Closed                  </option>;
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <textarea form = "bugStats" id = "comments" name = "comments['.$id.']" rows = "4" cols = "50">'.$comments.'</textarea>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    '.$email.'
                                </td>
                                <!-- <td>
                                    '.$wpuserid.'
                                </td> -->
                                <td>
                                    '.$requesttime.'
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <!-- <input id = "sub" type= "submit" name= "sub" value="UPDATE"/> -->
                                    <input form = "bugStats" type="checkbox" name="action_checkbox['.$id.']" value="'.$id.'"><br>
                                </td>
                            </tr>';
```

}

And here is the ajax call that processes it:

```
<script>

$("#bugStats").submit(function(event)
{
    var checked = $("#bugStats").serializeArray();
    alert("success");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ajax_updateBugStats.php',

        data: { checked: checked },
        success: function(server_response)
        {
            if(server_response == "1")
                alert("yes");
            else if (server_response == "0")
                alert("no");
            else
                alert("gro");
        }
        // error: AjaxFailed
    });
});
alert("nice");
</script>
```

Here is the php file that the ajax call uses (ajax_updateBugStats.php):

```
<?php
require_once 'wp-config.php';
require_once 'dbinclude.php';

$comments = array();
$status = array();

if (isset($_POST))
{

foreach($_POST['action_checkbox'] as $key => $value)
{
    $id[] = $_POST['bugID'][$key];
    $status[] = $_POST['status'][$key];
    $comments[] = $_POST['comments'][$key];
}
}

$count = count($_POST['action_checkbox']);
for ($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++)
{
$sqlstringWPUsers = "UPDATE bugtracker SET status = '{$status[$x]}', comments = '{$comments[$x]}' WHERE id = '{$id[$x]}'";
$resultWPUsers = mysqli_query($mysqlconn, $sqlstringWPUsers);

}
mysqli_close($con);


?>
```

Comment: Depending on what browser you're using, check out either the Chrome Javascript Panel (Ctrl+J) or Firebug and look at the network tab to see which page is being called by your ajax script to see if it's firing what you expect it to be firing.  Also something looks a little off in your HTML for the form but my brain isnt processing what right now.  Sorry!

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).